# Having both Follower and Following as ReferenceField in MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am working on a site, and I have both Followers and Following as two ReferenceFields attached to a User.  Is this overkill?  I felt like it might make the querying a little easier, but is this just asking for trouble in the long run?

Something like:

```
 class User(Document):
      name = StringField()
      followers = ListField(ReferenceField('User'))
      following = ListField(ReferenceField('User'))
```

I wasn't sure what best practice would be for this kind of relationship and if it's easier to just set one as a ReferenceField and filter when I query the database.  This would prevent instances where the follower and following list did not match, but it also seemed like it would make database queries more complicated.

I see this article on the mongodb website, which is helpful but I don't feel it directly answers my question https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/.